# How to correctly extract highlights and shadows from a grayscale image

Tags: android, image-processing, blending

I am drawing some buttons on the screen. Each with a different color, but the same shape, designed in Photoshop with all sort of reflections and shines.
I want to use a single bitmap of the shape and change its color programmatically, preserving all the reflections and shadows. This is what I do right now:

1. Get the shape into a ARRGB_8888 bitmap (even though all colors are shades of gray)
2. Copy the bitmap pixels to 3 buffers: Image, Highlights, Shadows
3. The reference grayshade is RGB[128,128,128]
4. In the Highlights buffer, zero all pixels below the reference (+ threshold)
5. In the Shadows buffer, zero all pixels above the reference (- threshold)
6. From the Highlights and Shadow buffers create Highlights and Shadow Bitmaps
7. Draw the original grayscale image using a `PorterDuffColorFilter` on mode MULTIPLY
8. Draw on top the shadows, using the Shadows bitmap and XferMode DARKEN
9. Draw on top the highlights, using the Highlights bitmap and XferMode LIGHTEN

I do get a result, but I realize that the final button color is not the target color, but a darker shade of it, because the MULTIPLY mode with a reference of 128 cuts all components in half.
I tried to set the reference to a whiter shade of gray, but then the highlights get saturated.
I tried to use SRC_IN on step 7 above, and I get the target color only on areas that are neither highlights nor shadows.

See the results:

[image: results]

Not sure what I need to ask, but I want to get the buttons with the exact target color and its highlights and shadows. Maybe I am generating the Highlights and Shadows masks wrong, or maybe I am using the wrong blending modes. Or maybe it is something else.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: I ended using photoshop, separated the highlights and shadow layers. Highlights with the base shape in black. Shadows with the base shape in white. Saved 3 files, the base shape in whitest level of gray I could manage, the shadows, the highlights, and proceeded as described in the question. Got a pretty close match to the desired color.